# Getting attribitue from session in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Hello I am writing a login registration page. Page is checking username password with database and when it is correct, user can access new jsp page. And it prints out " welcome + username". How can i do that ? I searched on the Internet and I foud below code. But it does not work. When I run it returns " welcome null". I want this in success.jsp

success.jsp

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body background="http://www.teamarking.com/barcode/bar_background.jpg"> 


 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>JSP Page</title>

  </head>
   <ul>
    <li><%
    out.println("<a href='music.jsp'>Music</a>");
    %>
    </li>
    <li><%
    out.println("<a href='sport.jsp'>Sport</a>");
    %></li>
     <li> <%
    out.println("<a href='stage.jsp'>Stage</a>");
    %></li>
     <li> <%
    out.println("<a href='family.jsp'>Family</a>");
    %></li>
    <li> <%
    out.println("<a href='education.jsp'>Education</a>");
    %></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="landscape">
  <%
  String username = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("username");
    session.setAttribute("username", username);

  out.println("welcome" + username);

  out.println(
        "<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");

  out.println(
        "<a href='myreservations.jsp'>My Reservations</a>");
  %>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

login.jsp

```
  <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
  <%
  String username = request.getParameter("username");
  String password = request.getParameter("password");
  Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/users", "users", "123");
  Statement st = con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs;
  rs = st.executeQuery("select * from users where username='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "'");
  if (rs.next()) {
    session.setAttribute("username", username);
    response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
  } else {
    out.println("Invalid password <a href='index.jsp'>try again</a>");
  }
  st.close();
  %>
```

Comment: Could you please show code where you put "username" into session attributes?

Comment: i updated my code

Answer (score 0):

Before you can read the attribute "username" you have to set the attribute. Therefore you have to use the function setAttribute().

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("username", nameOfUser);
```

You have to use this code after you have checked or verified the username and password. Can you show the rest of your code (the part where the verification occurs)?

Comment: how can i get this username value on another jsp page ?

Comment: That's strange. I think the code `session.setAttribute("username", username);` in success.jsp is not necessary. Can you try to change `request.getSession().getAttribute("username")` to `session.getAttribute("username")`.